# Convert ImageSize to FieldSize

Tags: dynamic, inputfield

How might I construct a function called `EmToPX[p]` such that the following 2 `InputField`s would be the same width.  If not please explain why doing such isn't possible.

```
InputField["a", ImageSize -> 100]
InputField["a", FieldSize -> EmToPX[100]]
```

After some trial an error ~7.2 appears to be the proper number of EMs above( `InputField["a", FieldSize -> 7.2]`), but after trying to convert to a function using proper ratios it appears such technique doesn't work very well.

```
EmToPX[p_] := (N[
    p (1.888888 + CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], "FontSize"]) ]);
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   InputField["a", ImageSize -> EmToPX[a]],
   InputField["a", FieldSize -> a],
   EmToPX[7.2]
   }]
 , {a, 1, 100}
 ]
```

**Background:** Ultimately I am working with `Grid` elements and would like an easy way to switch back and froth between `CellSize`,`ImageSize`,`ItemSize`,`FieldSize`.

Comment: You might want to also read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch#Computer_monitor_DPI_standards)

Comment: I believe this is effectively a duplicate but I cannot find the original.  Can anyone help?

Comment: If you're working with `Grid`, then for the love of all that is good and holy, don't do it this way.  Use `Pane` to define your constraints, and let `Grid` just snap itself to the `Pane` elements.

Comment: @JohnFultz You are quit right.  That does solve my most immediate problem.  I think it would be beneficial though if there there was a way to seamlessly add, and subtract between the EMs and pixels.  At minimum a reason why such can't be done.

Comment: Discussion about why it can't be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1462997/what-is-the-relationship-between-ems-and-pixels (implementations seem to vary though. Might be possible in MMA even if it shouldn't be possible...)

Comment: @Anon In CSS and HTML the most common implementation that I'm aware of  that isn't is correct.  Read the comment below the selected answer.  `In traditional typography it is. In CSS, however, it is the font height.`  I could be wrong but Mathematica is quit tied to the web's creation, and Wolfram did so many things so clean and elegantly that I doubt that he ignored the current web standard.

Comment: @LiamWilliam I read those answers before and still I was of the opinion that it would likely not be possible to find a relationship. CSS and MMA have nothing in common. But I now read the documentation for `FieldSize`: it seems you just have to figure out what the line height is and you're done. MMA has its own definition for em. They're not real ems.

Comment: @Anon You are quit right about the line height.  I believe the line-height in CSS defaults to the current font size.  I just hope we can determine how Mathematica determines the line height.  It doesn't appear to be in the Stylesheet or Option in the option inspector, but that is just after some quick searching.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard See above comment.

Comment: @István Thanks; that's the one.

Comment: @IstvánZachar Thank you for the link.